# How to ssh from a Ubuntu virtual machine to machines in the same LAN as the host PC?

Tags: ssh, virtual-machine, virtualbox

[image]

Here is my setup (sorry for the poor painting):

- Two physical PCs are connected via an Ethernet cable.
- PC1 is running windows and PC2 is running Ubuntu.
- `ssh` service is running on PC2 and PC1 can ssh to PC2.
- A virtualbox virtual machine is running ubuntu on PC1.

I would like to be able to ssh from the virtual machine to PC2. Is that possible?

Comment: Try going into the Settings in VirtualBox and making sure the Ubuntu VM has a **Bridged Adapter** before starting the VM.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks for the solution! It worked!